# How to load N-TRIPLE file in apache jena?

Tags: jena, n-triples

I am quite new to RDF and Jena. I want load a `.nt (N- TRIPLE)` file to a model. I have tried `read(inputStream, "N-TRIPLE")` but did not help.

It throws

```
org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName.
```

Can anyone point me out what is wrong?

Here is the link for the `N-TRiple` file which I tried to load : http://dbpedia.org/data/Berlin.ntriples

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`read(inputStream, string)` uses the string argument as the base URI, not the syntax language.  It's trying the default, which is RDF/XML. Check the javadoc for [Model#read(InputStream in, String base)](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#read%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) and [Model#read(InputStream in, String base, String lang)](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#read%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for more information.

```
model.read(inputStream, null, "N-TRIPLES") ;
```

or

```
RDFDataMgr.read(model, inputStream, LANG.NTRIPLES) ;
```

If you are just opening the stream from a file (or URL) then Apache Jena will sort out the details.  E.g.,

```
RDFDataMgr.read(model, "file:///myfile.nt") ;
```

There are various related operations. See the javadoc for [Model](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html) and [RDFDataMgr](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/riot/RDFDataMgr.html).